# react-simple-validator Validation not working in functional component with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use is in the functional component using React Hooks but its now showing up the validation message on UI

My React version is below
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",

Below is my code, Please check if I am missing anything.

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleReactValidator from "simple-react-validator";

export default function ExampleForm (){
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    title: '',
    email:'',
  });

  const  handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const validator = new SimpleReactValidator({
    className: 'text-danger',
    messages: {
      email: 'That is not an email.',
    }
  });

  const submitForm= ()=> {
    if (validator.allValid()) {
      alert('You submitted the form!');
    } else {
      validator.showMessages();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input className="form-control" value={values.title}  onChange=handleChange("title")} />
 

        {validator.message('title', values.title, 'required|alpha')}
 
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input className="form-control" value={values.email} onChange=handleChange("email")} />
 
        {validator.message('email', values.email, 'required|email')}
 
      </div>

      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submitForm.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: validation message showing without click submit

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
const validator = useRef(new SimpleReactValidator())
```

Because when you use the way you mentioned you should use forceUpdate() and this function doesn't exist only in the class component